# Wpf persisting application project in one file

Tags: wpf, serialization

I'm developing some digramming editor in wpf. So in editor you have project, diagrams, elements, connections etc... And now I have to implement load and save for project. I will persist project into one file. So what do you think is the best approach for doing this? Serialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can using serialization properties of element in your diagram.
See:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx